# How to import another python script (.py) into main python file

Tags: python, json, python-import

is there a way to import multiple python files into a main python file?

I have a bunch of py files and each one has to run in the main python file and the data are saved into a json file.

This is what I tried and it gave me an error.

```
import light.py as light
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in  _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/majorproject/pillar1.py", line 8, in <module>
import sensorkey.py as sensorkey
ImportError: No module named 'sensorkey.py'; 'sensorkey' is not a package
```

I have also tried specifying the path to the py file and it didn't work either and keeps giving an invalid syntax error.

```
import /home/pi/Desktop/json/light.py as light
```

Update: 
I managed to fix the import error but i now, after importing this light.py file, i have to print out certain keys from a dictionary (key) into this new file then export it to a json file. I'm currently using TinyDB to do so. Here are my codes:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
import json
from light import key

with open("/home/pi/Desktop/json/sensortestest.json", 'w+'):
    db = TinyDB('/home/pi/Desktop/json/sensortestest.json')
    table = db.table('Light')
    db.insert_multiple([{'Key 1' :key[lightkey]}, {'Key 2' : key[lightkeyID]}])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/majorproject/testertestest.py", line 12, in <module>
    db.insert_multiple([{'Key 1' :key[lightkey]}, {'Key 2' : key[lightkeyID]}])
```

NameError: name 'lightkey' is not defined

The problem is I had already defined 'lightkey'  in its own file already.

Comment: Try `from ...json import light`

Comment: It sounds like you need to read about [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules) and [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: I am trying to import a .py file into another. I've tried import light.py as light but it didnt work because of the .py extension. so i removed it but it gave me another error that a dict is not defined but i defined it in its own file already

Comment: Your errors is not related to `light.py` importing because if your file couldn't be imported your error will be `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'light'` but yours is different

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To include the dictionary, you could do this if your file location is in different directory (with caution of path.append as [@Coldspeed mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44491453/2306662)):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/foo/bar/")
from light import *
```

If it is in same directory as current directory, you could just do:

```
from light import *
```

Comment: thank you so much! it runs! By the way, if i just do '' from light import * ''  , it runs everything that the light file is supposed to print right? If i just want to print out a certain key and not running the  whole script, what should i do?

Answer (score 10):

The syntax for importing `your_filename.py`, assuming it is in the same directory, is

```
import your_filename
```

In your case, it would be

```
import light
```

Note the absence of `.py`.

If your file is in a different directory, you'll need to do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/dir/containing/your_filename.py')
import your_filename
```

Note that appending to `sys.path` is dangerous, and should not be done unless you know what you're doing.

Read more at the [official docs for import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I tried that but it's giving me another error. I will update it above

Comment: @DanielWinser The syntax is `import sensorkey`, or `import light`.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. turns out, i just had to do a "from light import  * " because the file is in the same directory. But now, the thing is that i wan to print out certain keys from this light file and not all of it becuase right now, * runs the whole script and prints out all the keys. How to i specify what to print without printing all the keys in the light file?

Comment: sorry, i meant a dictionary. i tried to import a dictionary from the file but it said that the dictionary is not defined. Let me update the question yeah? Thanks for the help!! you're a lifesaver!

Comment: @DanielWinser you have to import lightkey too.

Comment: it says that i "cannot import name lightkey"

Comment: @DanielWinser on second thought. If you have a different issue than what was mentioned in the question, you should open a new one and provide a minimal verifiable example. In the present state, I won't be able to help.

Comment: Alright! thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it! @Coldspeed